# React: Rendering large images & Zooming in

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create an app using React, where a user could upload a high-resolution image and zoom in on it to select points/coordinates.

The issue that I'm having is that when the image renders (with its original resolution size) it's far too large to show on the screen. I would like to somehow scale down the image size while maintaining its resolution. Ideally, I would like to show 50% of its original size and when zoomed in, I would be able to select coordinates/pixels based off the original size.

Also, if anyone has a great react/javascript library that has a great high-level zoom functionality, please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could display image inside a container with hidden overflow and control image top and left offsets using js/css as well as image zoom. Then use these values (image size, top/left offsets, original size, scale) to reverse calculate the coordinates.

Comment: wow, that's a very creative answer! i think that might just work, thank you!